# Why do UITextFields Clip Text in editor Xcode 9.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

Hey guys I know that when running your app the text fields work fine , but in the storyboard it is super frustrating not being able to edit the look and text of UITextFields due to clipping. Does anyone know why this is and any potential fixes to make this work better?

why does it show like this : [image]

I can see the text entered when I increase the font size , but for this project I dont want that large of text.

**Goal**

Find out why text is clipping and see if there is a fix.